# Oracle SQL - Return rows where there is at least one row in a group for the current month and there has been a change in class in a previous month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to output rows that meet the following conditions:

- At least one row for the ClientID must be in the current month (only interested in the most recent row for the Client ID in that month)
- The class in current month for the ClientID is different to the immediately previous row from an earlier month for the ClientID

My data can have multiple rows per client per month and I am only interested in the latest row per month per client.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
ID      Client ID  Class    Date
14609   87415      C        04/DEC/18
13859   87415      X        16/AUG/18
11906   87415      C        27/FEB/17
10667   87415      B        23/JAN/17
14538   132595     D        03/DEC/18
14567   141805     C        04/DEC/18
14411   141805     A        27/NOV/18
```

Desired Output based on the above is:

```
ID      Client ID  Class    Date
14609   87415      C        04/DEC/18
13859   87415      X        16/AUG/18
14567   141805     C        04/DEC/18
14411   141805     A        27/NOV/18
```

I have had multiple attempts at this with zero success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My attempts have not been able to find the immediately previous row. :/

```
select * from
(
select drh.defaultriskhistid, drh.clientid, cv.description, 
drh.updatetimestamp
from default_risk_history drh 
inner join code_values cv on drh.defaultriskcodeid = cv.codevalueid
where
defaultriskhistid in
(select max(defaultriskhistid) from default_risk_history
group by clientid, ltrim(TO_CHAR(updatetimestamp,'mm-yyyy'),'0'))
) t
where
(
Select count(*) from default_risk_history drh1 where drh1.clientid = 
t.clientid and ltrim(TO_CHAR(drh1.updatetimestamp,'mm-yyyy'),'0') = 
ltrim(TO_CHAR(current_date,'mm-yyyy'),'0')
) >=1
order by clientid, updatetimestamp desc
```

Comment: Hello Vamsi, I have added my 'attempt' :(

Comment: Can you add an example (or more details) for the case with multiple rows per month regarding *immediately previous row from an earlier month*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the two most recent rows, if they have different classes and the most recent one is in the current month.  If so:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(date) over (partition by clientid) as max_date,
             lag(class) over (partition by client_id order by date) as prev_class,
             lead(class) over (partition by client_id order by date) as next_class,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where max_date >= trunc(sysdate, 'MON') and
      ( (seqnum = 1 and prev_class <> class) or
        (seqnum = 2 and next_class <> class)
      );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this worked perfectly.  Im not going to admit how long I attempted to get the result I was after - complete novice.  Lets just say it was a long time.. lol

Comment: @calco If you're a novice, you'll want to look into "window functions" or the Oracle proprietary name "analytic functions." These are functions that are able to examine *neighboring rows* to produce a result for the current row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (client_id, class, datum) as
  2    (select 87415, 'c', date '2018-12-04' from dual union all
  3     select 87415, 'x', date '2018-08-16' from dual union all
  4     select 87415, 'c', date '2017-02-27' from dual union all
  5     select 87415, 'b', date '2017-01-23' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 132595, 'd', date '2018-12-03' from dual union all
  8     select 141805, 'c', date '2018-12-04' from dual union all
  9     select 141805, 'a', date '2018-11-27' from dual
 10    ),
 11  inter as
 12    (select client_id,
 13       class,
 14       datum,
 15       lag(class) over (partition by client_id order by datum desc) prev_class,
 16       row_number() over (partition by client_id order by datum desc) rn
 17     from test
 18    )
 19  select client_id, class, datum
 20  from inter
 21  where (class <> prev_class or prev_class is null)
 22    and client_id in (select client_id from inter
 23                      group by client_id
 24                      having max(rn) >= 2
 25                     )
 26    and rn <= 2
 27  order by client_id, datum desc;

 CLIENT_ID C DATUM
---------- - ----------
     87415 c 04.12.2018
     87415 x 16.08.2018
    141805 c 04.12.2018
    141805 a 27.11.2018

SQL>
```